# Looking for the documentation of the qcow2c disk image format

Tags: openstack, qemu

I know that **qcow2** is a file format for disk image files used by QEMU but I found that CentOS provides some cloud images in the **qcow2c** format (with a c at the end) [here](https://cloud.centos.org/centos/7/images/).

I assume it's a compressed version of the qcow2 but I didn't find any information related to it on the QEMU documentation or in OpenStack documentation (note that the qcow2c is accepted when uploading an image in OpenStack).

I would like to have some documentation on the qcow2c format and to know how to do a conversion between the qcow2 and the qcow2c formats. The idea is to start from a qcow2 image, do some tweaking on this image using the *virt-sysprep* utility and then convert it into the qcow2c to save disk space.

Answer (score 8):

According to [this mailing list thread](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2014-December/020807.html) from 2014:

> File: CentOS-7-x86_64-GenericCloud-20141129_01.qcow2c
>
> Desc: This is the same image, run through the qemu qcow2 internal compression setup - while this image is suiteable *[sic]* for development and play, it comes with non trivial i/o performance penalties and therefore not recommended for production.

This is not any kind of standard format rather a CentOS convention.

The documentation is open source, I believe [the downloads page](https://wiki.centos.org/Download?highlight=%28qcow2c%29) would be the appropriate place to add the documentation as it describes the other downloads to some extent.  The wiki is open for everyone to edit!